# SQL DB2 CHECK-CONSTRAINT PATTERN

Tags: sql, db2, check-constraints

I'm trying to write a constraint pattern which only allows the following: a string as follows:

- '+55'
- one blank space
- a number between 120 and 150
- one blank space
- 7-9 digits.

I tried a lot of ways but none of it worked the way i hoped and ended up doing something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE KUNDENKONTAKTDATEN
ADD CONSTRAINT 

VariableA_Check CHECK (
VariableA Like '+55 1[2-4][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'    
Or VariableA Like '+55 1[2-4][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'   
Or VariableA Like '+55 1[2-4][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  
Or VariableA Like '+55 150 [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  
Or VariableA Like '+55 150 [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'    
Or VariableA Like '+55 150 [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Not really pretty but hoped it would work. Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: 8-10 digits not 7-9, my mistake!

Comment: Db2 11.1 allows regular expressions - this would solve your problem if you are on Linux, Unix or Windows. Check out regexp_like - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html

Comment: thanks - but I'm still wondering why the solution above wouldn't work.

Comment: ok, i tried the regular expression solution and it wouldn't work at all since regexp_like is not valid in check-constraints.

Comment: Why don't you use substring as SUBSTR(VariableA,1,3) = '+55' And SUBSTR(VariableA,4,1) = ' ' And SUBSTR(VariableA,5,3) > '120' And SUBSTR(VariableA,5,3) < '150' And SUBSTR(VariableA,8,1) = ' ' And SUBSTR(VariableA,9,1) > '7' And SUBSTR(VariableA,9,1) < '9'

Comment: @Bernie regular expressions ARE allowed in check constraints and I have used it before - here is an example i used create table checktelno (id int, telno varchar(50)
check (regexp_like(telno, '^(\+[0-9]{2,3})[\d\s\/\(\)-]+')) );

Comment: In SQL, `LIKE` only supports the wildcards `%` and `_`. The `[2-4]` has no special meaning for `LIKE`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Db2 Version 11.1 on Linux/Unix Windows, then try something like this:

```
create table tester (
 mycol varchar(50) constraint bad_value check  (regexp_like(mycol, '^\+55 (12[0-9]|13[0-9]|14[0-9]|150) [0-9]{8,10}$'))
);
```

You can use [this website](https://regex101.com/) to test out and explain the regular expression.

Comment: Or if using 9.7 or higher, you can use regex by calling an xquery function.